# Using Func instead of switch for methods with different signature in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to refactor switch case statements in C#.
I have used the below code and it was working well. But now I have got to change the code. One method has a different signature[it has no parameters] while other methods take one parameter.
Can someone please help me in modifying the code for methods with different signatures?

```cs
Dictionary<string, Func<SqlDataReader, object>> methods = new Dictionary<string, Func<SqlDataReader, object>>();
methods = LoadMethodNames();
return methods[key].Invoke(reader); // key = A or B

private Dictionary<string, Func<SqlDataReader, object>> LoadMethodNames()
{
    Dictionary<string, Func<SqlDataReader, object>> s= new Dictionary<string, Func<SqlDataReader, object>>();
    s.Add("A", A);
    s.Add("B", B); return s; }


private object A(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    return new object; 
}

private object B(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    return new object; 
}
```

Now the change is in Method B:

```cs
private object B() { return new object; }
```

Comment: You can´t put different types of `Func` into one single collection, as they don´t have *anything* in common. Thus `Func<SqlDataReader, object>` is completely unrelated to `Func<object>`. But why not simply leave the parameter within `B` as it is, simply not using it? Or omit it from `A` *and* `B`?

Comment: Yes I tried doing that. But SonarQube doesn't allow me. It shows as a major issue :P 
Also, it would be useful if, in future, I have to add/remove the parameters.

Comment: You can´t modify the methods signatures without changing the declaration of the dictionary also. But again, `Func<SqlDataReader, object>` and `Func<object>` are not compatible.

Comment: Yup !! is there any other approach apart from mine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with an extra level of indirection; simply wrap the call without parameters in one with an argument that will be ignored:

```
s.Add("B", reader => B());
```

You could add, if necessary, a safety net making sure that the passed in reader is `null`:

```
s.Add("B", reader => { Debug.Assert(reader == null); return B(); });
```

Do bear in mind that this is nothing short of a hack. If you are expecting frequent signature variations then you'll have to rethink your strategy because the current solution will not cut it; there isn't a common `Func` that can represent delegates with different signatures.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. As of now, it worked. I think I need to go for Chain Responsibility/ Polymorphism for future changes.